# Get current NSDate in timestamp format

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter, unix-timestamp

I have a basic method which gets the current time and sets it in a string. However, how can I get it to format the current date & time in a UNIX since-1970 timestamp format?

Here is my code:

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
```

Is it possible to use `NSDateFormatter` to change the 'resultString' into a timestamp?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Here's what I use:

```
NSString * timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
```

(times 1000 for milliseconds, otherwise, take that out)

If You're using it all the time, it might be nice to declare a macro

```
#define TimeStamp [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000]
```

Then Call it like this:

```
NSString * timestamp = TimeStamp;
```

Or as a method:

```
- (NSString *) timeStamp {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
}
```

As TimeInterval

```
- (NSTimeInterval) timeStamp {
    return [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
}
```

NOTE:

The 1000 is to convert the timestamp to milliseconds.  You can remove this if you prefer your timeInterval in seconds.

**Swift**

If you'd like a global variable in Swift, you could use this:

```
var Timestamp: String {
    return "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"
}
```

Then, you can call it

```
println("Timestamp: \(Timestamp)")
```

Again, the `*1000` is for miliseconds, if you'd prefer, you can remove that.  If you want to keep it as an `NSTimeInterval`

```
var Timestamp: NSTimeInterval {
    return NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
}
```

Declare these outside of the context of any class and they'll be accessible anywhere.

Comment: No problem, I updated with the Macro I use in case it's helpful for your situation!

Comment: Thanks @Logan but I'm pretty sure macro's are always discouraged. You can easily lose understanding of a big program with macros. It would be best just to make a method which does this and is called whenever you need it.

Comment: BTW - if you're adding the value to a dictionary, you can just do: `@{@"timestamp": @([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970])`

Answer (score 15):

use `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]`

Comment: `@([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]).stringValue`

Answer (score 7):

```
- (void)GetCurrentTimeStamp
    {
        NSDateFormatter *objDateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [objDateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSString    *strTime = [objDateformat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSString    *strUTCTime = [self GetUTCDateTimeFromLocalTime:strTime];//You can pass your date but be carefull about your date format of NSDateFormatter.
        NSDate *objUTCDate  = [objDateformat dateFromString:strUTCTime];
        long long milliseconds = (long long)([objUTCDate timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);

        NSString *strTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",milliseconds];
NSLog(@"The Timestamp is = %@",strTimeStamp);
    }

 - (NSString *) GetUTCDateTimeFromLocalTime:(NSString *)IN_strLocalTime
    {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate  *objDate    = [dateFormatter dateFromString:IN_strLocalTime];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
        NSString *strDateTime   = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:objDate];
        return strDateTime;
    }
```

NOTE :- The Timestamp must be in UTC Zone, So I convert our local Time to UTC Time.

Comment: your GetCurrentTimeStamp() has a couple lowercase issues.  cut and paste into Xcode to see

Comment: Please Use This "NSString *strTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",milliseconds];
NSLog(@"The Timestamp is = %@",strTimeStamp);"

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to call this method directly on an NSDate object and get the timestamp as a string in milliseconds without any decimal places, define this method as a category:

```
@implementation NSDate (MyExtensions)
- (NSString *)unixTimestampInMilliseconds
{
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [self timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//      The following method would return you timestamp after converting to milliseconds. [RETURNS STRING]

```
- (NSString *) timeInMiliSeconds
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSString * timeInMS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", [@(floor([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)) longLongValue]];
    return timeInMS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also use

```
@(time(nil)).stringValue);
```

for timestamp in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It's convenient to define a macro for get current timestamp

```
class Constant {
    struct Time {
        let now = { round(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) } // seconds
    }
}
```

Then you can use `let timestamp = Constant.Time.now()`

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

I have a UILabel which shows TimeStamp over a Camera Preview.

```
    var timeStampTimer : NSTimer?
    var dateEnabled:  Bool?
    var timeEnabled: Bool?
   @IBOutlet weak var timeStampLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//Setting Initial Values to be false.
        dateEnabled =  false
        timeEnabled =  false
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        //Current Date and Time on Preview View
        timeStampLabel.text = timeStamp
        self.timeStampTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0,target: self, selector: Selector("updateCurrentDateAndTimeOnTimeStamperLabel"),userInfo: nil,repeats: true)
}

func updateCurrentDateAndTimeOnTimeStamperLabel()
    {
//Every Second, it updates time.

        switch (dateEnabled, timeEnabled) {
        case (true?, true?):
            timeStampLabel.text =  NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .LongStyle, timeStyle: .MediumStyle)
            break;
        case (true?, false?):
            timeStampLabel.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .LongStyle, timeStyle: .NoStyle)
            break;

        case (false?, true?):
            timeStampLabel.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .NoStyle, timeStyle: .MediumStyle)
            break;
        case (false?, false?):
            timeStampLabel.text =  NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .NoStyle, timeStyle: .NoStyle)
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
    }
```

I am setting up a setting Button to trigger a alertView.

```
@IBAction func settingsButton(sender : AnyObject) {


let cameraSettingsAlert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Please choose a course", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let timeStampOnAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Time Stamp on Photo", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

    self.dateEnabled = true
    self.timeEnabled =  true

}
let timeStampOffAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("TimeStamp Off", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

    self.dateEnabled = false
    self.timeEnabled =  false

}
let dateOnlyAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Date Only", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

    self.dateEnabled = true
    self.timeEnabled =  false


}
let timeOnlyAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Time Only", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

    self.dateEnabled = false
    self.timeEnabled =  true
}

let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: .Cancel) { action in

}
cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(cancel)
cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(timeStampOnAction)
cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(timeStampOffAction)
cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(dateOnlyAction)
cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(timeOnlyAction)

self.presentViewController(cameraSettingsAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate new];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *strDateTime = [formatter stringFromDate:todaysDate];

NSString *strFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/Shared/Recording_%@.mov",strDateTime];
NSLog(@"filename:%@",strFileName);
```

Log will be : filename:/Users/Shared/Recording_06-28-2016 12:53:26.mov

Answer (score 0):

If you need time stamp as a string.

```
time_t result = time(NULL);                
NSString *timeStampString = [@(result) stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

**To get timestamp from NSDate Swift 3**

```
func getCurrentTimeStampWOMiliseconds(dateToConvert: NSDate) -> String {
    let objDateformat: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    objDateformat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let strTime: String = objDateformat.string(from: dateToConvert as Date)
    let objUTCDate: NSDate = objDateformat.date(from: strTime)! as NSDate
    let milliseconds: Int64 = Int64(objUTCDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
    let strTimeStamp: String = "\(milliseconds)"
    return strTimeStamp
}
```

**To use**

```
let now = NSDate()
let nowTimeStamp = self.getCurrentTimeStampWOMiliseconds(dateToConvert: now)
```