# How do I get timestamp interval in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp

I saw this answer : [Get current NSDate in timestamp format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359090/get-current-time-in-timestamp-format-ios)

But for some reason it gives me errors.

What I need is to be able to specify the timestamp between now and in the next 2 minutes, or interval between last 2 minutes and now.

Eg: interval => now-2minutes to now (Time between previous 2 minutes and now)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right, this should clarify things for you:

```
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let now = NSDate()

    let comps = NSDateComponents()
    comps.minute = 2

    let twoMinutesFromNow = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(comps, toDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchStrictly)

    let interval = twoMinutesFromNow?.timeIntervalSinceDate(now)
```

[Here](http://nshipster.com/nscalendar-additions/) is a nice article about handling `NSDate`s with the use of `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`

Comment: so now -> had current timestamp, and twoMinutesFromNow has the timestamp after adding 2 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

```
var curr = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 10000)
var timestep = curr
```

Comment: If curr is the current timestamp,if I add 20000,then it is the timestamp of 2 mins later right?